# Count field is incorrect

Tags: .net, postgresql, odbc, fastreport

I am using FastReport .NET

[image]

I have a SQL query in Postgres:

```
select * from product where idproduct =: param
```

But when I run an error it displays:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [07002] [Devart]
>   [ODBC] COUNT field incorrect

Comment: select * from product where idproduct = :param

Comment: Already figured out? Put it in answer and accepted it so this question will not show in unanswered..